# SwiftUI animations affecting modal background

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a sheet with a simple animation inside of ListView():

```
        .overlay(
                ZStack{
                Group {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .opacity(animatingButton ? 0.2 : 0)
                        .frame(width: 68, height: 68, alignment: .center)
                        .scaleEffect(animatingButton ? 1 : 0)
                    
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .opacity(animatingButton ? 0.15 : 0)
                        .frame(width: 88, height: 88, alignment: .center)
                        .scaleEffect(animatingButton ? 1 : 0)
                }
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: true))
```

resulting in circles growing and shrinking in size.

Inside the modal I have a TabView and am setting a background image set like so:

```
TabView(selection: $VM.modalSelectedPage){
ListView()
    .background(Image(VM.backgroundImage)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)) 

....

}
```

The problem is that this animation is causing unwanted behaviour when dragging up from the bottom of the modal, if I comment out

```
  .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: true))
```

the problem goes away.

I have tried adding

```
.animation(nil)
```

to .background which doesn't work.

Here you can see the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZIIe.jpg

Here you can see it working without animation:https://i.stack.imgur.com/92NFh.jpg

**Simple code to replicate bug**

**ModalView:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ModalView: View {

var body: some View {
    
        
        HStack{
            Text("")
                .animation(.default) // Comment out to fix issue
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.green)                                                             
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

**ContentView:**

```
import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView: View {
    
        @State private var showingModal = false
    
        var body: some View {
            Button(action: {
            self.showingModal.toggle()   
        }, label: {
            Text("Open Modal")
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingModal, content: {
            ModalView()
        }) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example to debug.

Comment: Can you please provide some more info like screenshots?

Comment: @Asperi I have appended simple reproducible code to my original post.

Comment: @Dc7 You can find imgur links to videos of the issue in my original post.